# Deploy lift application on Tomcat

Tags: scala, tomcat, lift

I have a problem at deploying a lift application on a Tomcat Server. 
At server start the log shows an error:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive lift.war
Nov 08, 2013 5:47:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Nov 08, 2013 5:47:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/lift] startup failed due to previous errors
```

The error occurs on either Tomcat 6 and 7 with lift Version 2.6 with scala 2.10.3 on Tomcat 7

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here's the stack trace from Tomcat:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception starting filter LiftFilter
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.Map()Lscala/collection/immutable/Map$;
at net.liftweb.common.BoxTrait$class.$init$(Box.scala:62)
at net.liftweb.common.Box$.<init>(Box.scala:49)
at net.liftweb.common.Box$.<clinit>(Box.scala)
at net.liftweb.util.Props$.mode$lzycompute(Props.scala:112)
at net.liftweb.util.Props$.mode(Props.scala:110)
at net.liftweb.util.Props$.devMode$lzycompute(Props.scala:204)
at net.liftweb.util.Props$.devMode(Props.scala:204)
at net.liftweb.http.LiftRules$.<init>(LiftRules.scala:79)
at net.liftweb.http.LiftRules$.<clinit>(LiftRules.scala)
at net.liftweb.http.provider.servlet.ServletFilterProvider$class.init(ServletFilterProvider.scala:38)
at net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter.init(LiftServlet.scala:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT:
Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "lift_project"

version := "0.0.1"

organization := "net.liftweb"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots"     at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
              "staging"       at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging",
              "releases"      at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
             )

seq(com.github.siasia.WebPlugin.webSettings :_*)

unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "lib" }

unmanagedJars in Compile <<= baseDirectory map { base => (base ** "*.jar").classpath }

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+= (baseDirectory) { _ / "src/main/webapp" }

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature", "-language:implicitConversions", "-language:postfixOps")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "2.6-M1"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb"       %% "lift-webkit"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
    "net.liftweb"       %% "lift-mapper"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
    "net.liftweb"       %% "lift-ldap"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp"        % "8.1.7.v20120910"  % "container,test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container,test" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
    "ch.qos.logback"    % "logback-classic"     % "1.0.6",
    "com.h2database"    % "h2"                  % "1.3.167",
    "mysql"             % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25",
    "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default"
  )
}

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

EDIT:
And the content of the lib folder:

```
activation-1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
h2-1.3.167.jar
htmlparser-1.4.jar
iText-2.1.5.jar
jcommon-1.0.18.jar
jfreechart-1.0.15.jar
jfreechart-1.0.15-demo.jar
jfreechart-1.0.15-experimental.jar
jfreechart-1.0.15-swt.jar
joda-convert-1.2.jar
joda-time-2.1.jar
junit.jar
lift-actor_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-common_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-db_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-json_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-ldap_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-mapper_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-markdown_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-proto_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-util_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
lift-webkit_2.10-2.6-M1.jar
logback-classic-1.0.6.jar
logback-core-1.0.6.jar
mail-1.4.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.25.jar
paranamer-2.4.1.jar
sbt-launch.jar
scala-compiler.jar
scala-library.jar
scalap-2.10.0.jar
scala-reflect-2.10.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
swtgraphics2d.jar
```

Comment: The information in the log file is not sufficient to see the cause of the problem. The interesting bit is

"SEVERE: Error filterStart"

You might want to check the other log files for more information.

Comment: I editet the Question with the Stacktrace produced by Tomcat

Comment: Can you also post your `build.sbt` or whatever defines your dependencies? In particular, I'm curious as to which `Lift` jars you are using and which `Scala` libraries you have.

Comment: Could you also post the list of jars from your WEB-INF/lib folder (from the unpacked war)? There seems to a library missing, or a version mismatch.

Comment: -1 for editing question so much that it becomes another question. I'm deleting my answer because it's not relevant anymore.

Comment: Don't see why it has become another question. The problem (running the lift application on a tomcat) is still the same. The edits are responses to the comments on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using some try&error methods I finally identified the jar causing trouble:

> sbt-launch.jar

After removing this from the lib folder everything works fine on Tomcat (and Jetty as well)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I guess the problem lies here:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile <<= baseDirectory map { base => (base ** "*.jar").classpath }
```

This simply adds every jar under your project to the WAR. I don't know which SBT version you're using but IIRC older versions of SBT put scala-library.jar in their build path under your project root (baseDirectory), which, in your case, gets included during the build process, resulting in a jar conflict.

Try removing the suspected line or change 'baseDirectory' to something more specific like 'unmanagedBase'.

Comment: I edited my Question, it was a liite bit confusing. My Problem isn't the servlet jar but the Error-Message "Error filterStart", caused by a  "No Such Method"-Exception

Comment: That didn't work. I left out the line in the build.sbt, but nothing changed

Comment: You may have to put your project to Github (with confidential stuff removed) so that we can check what's really going on. Also, please specify which SBT version you're using if its launcher jar is not part of the project.

Comment: SBT Version is 0.13.0.
GitHub might not be as simple as it sounds, but i'll try

Answer (score 0):

scala-library.jar does look suspicious, as we cannot tell the version from the file name. Maybe it is an old standard library, for which your lift version is not working.

Try

```
unzip -p scala-library.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

to see the version, you need it to be 2.10.0 or newer.

I agree with [harp seal pup](https://stackoverflow.com/users/877349/harp-seal-pup) that the problem is probably caused by your copying of the unmanaged jars. Try not to use unmanaged jars (remove the line, let sbt manage the dependencies).

Comment: The Version of the bundle is `2.10.3.v20130923-060037-VFINAL-e2fec6b28d`.
I left out the line in the build.sbt, but didn't change anything.

Comment: Has the Tomcat installation been modified? Maybe additional jars have been put into lib? Have you tried it with a fresh, clean Tomcat download, with nothing else deployed?

Comment: At work I use the XAMPP (WAMPP) Installation, but the tomcat folder has never been touched. At home I use a clean tomcat from the ubuntu repository. Both systems are throwing the same error.